# Copy whitespace from string to string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, whitespace

I want to copy whitespace like spaces and tabs from string to string in Python 2.
For example if I have a string with 3 spaces at first and one tab at the end like "   Hi\t" I want to copy those whitespace to another string for example string like "hello" would become "   hello\t"
Is that possible to do easily?

Comment: Yes, using regular expressions. Are you expecting to *only* take whitespace from the beginning and end of strings? If not, it gets a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is of course possible. I would use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for that.

```
import re

hi = " Hi\t"
hello = "hello"

spaces = re.match(r"^(\s*).+?(\s*)$", hi)
if spaces:
    left, right = spaces.groups()
    string = "{}{}{}".format(left, hello, right)
    print(string)
    # Out: " hello\t"
```

Comment: The `.*` in your regex is greedy. To avoid conflicts, you could change the regex to `^(\s*).+?(\s*)$` (i.e. make the mid part lazy).

Comment: @jbndlr Indeed, big mistake. Thank you!